# Linux cmd line: How to filter a string by NOT wanted patterns

Tags: linux, bash, grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Debian Linux:

I'm wanting to do a search and then filter it by those lines that do NOT begin with "/mnt/c/" or "/mnt/x/", my current disks (I'm working on WSL).

So then I write: `locate $str | grep /[!cx]

I learned a bit about wildcards but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `grep` regexes rather than shell wildcards:

```
locate "$str" | grep -v '^/mnt/[cx]/'
```

Put quotes around `$variable` as a matter of routine — there are occasions not to do so, but they are rare.

The `-v` option to `grep` means "print the lines that don't match".  The regex `'^/mnt/[cx]/'` means lines that start with `/mnt/c/` or `/mnt/x/`, so in conjunction with `-v` that means "only print lines that don't start with `/mnt/c/` or `/mnt/x/`.

I'm blithely assuming that the `locate` command provides the data you want to filter.

Comment: omg the `  -v  ` solved my life, I was screwing up my life, thanks <3